# Is there a way I can subtract a period of time from a date in the format 'mm/dd/yy' in python?

Tags: python

I've currently got a file with a list of dates and want to be able to see which dates are over a year old.

So far I've got:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

with open('dates.doc', 'r') as file:              
    lines = file.readlines()

search ='/'
for line in lines:
    if search in line:
        dates = line.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:'' ')
        stripped = dates.strip('\n')
        print(stripped)
```

Which is just collecting the date from the file in the 'mm/dd/yy' format stripping other data.

I've also set a year limit, but I'm not sure how to run through the file and check if the data is before the limit and if it is print it:

```
datelimit = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you look into RE as the optimal mechanism for isolating your date. What you have there is unlikely to produce the desired results.

Comment: convert both dates to `ordinal` form (number) and subtract both numbers to see how many days old it is

Comment: @JCaesar The ordinal number is the proleptic Gregorian ordinal of the date, it has nothing to do with leap years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, using a regular expression will give you more reliable results when determining the existence (or otherwise) of a date in the format you've specified. This example will not provide totally reliable results if the pattern matches but is not, in fact, a valid date. For example, 99/99/99 would match but is obviously nonsensical.

The DELTA value is in years. Thus, in this example, dates that are over a year old (from the present day) will be printed.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = datetime.today()

DELTA = 1

with open('dates.doc') as file:              
    for line in file:
        if (m := re.search(r'.*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}).*', line)):
            d = datetime.strptime(m[1], '%m/%d/%y')
            if relativedelta(today, d).years >= DELTA:
                print(m[1])
```

Comment: If you could flag my answer as useful I'd be grateful